# I am getting error while implementing while initialize exoplayer2 inside adapter and implementing adapter on viewpager2

Tags: android, adapter, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x, android-viewpager2

```
    2020-07-21 08:42:55.515 15624-16608/com.app.videopreloading E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Renderer error: index=0, type=video, format=Format(1, null, null, video/avc, null, -1, null, [360, 640, 24.999998], [-1, -1]), rendererSupport=YES
        com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer$DecoderInitializationException: Decoder init failed: OMX.Exynos.avc.dec, Format(1, null, null, video/avc, null, -1, null, [360, 640, 24.999998], [-1, -1])
            at com.google.android.exoplayer2.BaseRenderer.createRendererException(BaseRenderer.java:359)
            at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.maybeInitCodec(MediaCodecRenderer.java:560)
            at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.onInputFormatChanged(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1240)
            at com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.MediaCodecVideoRenderer.onInputFormatChanged(MediaCodecVideoRenderer.java:755)
            at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.readToFlagsOnlyBuffer(MediaCodecRenderer.java:801)
            at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.render(MediaCodecRenderer.java:700)
            at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.doSomeWork(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:599)
            at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:329)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
            at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
         Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer$DecoderInitializationException: Decoder init failed: OMX.Exynos.avc.dec, Format(1, null, null, video/avc, null, -1, null, [360, 640, 24.999998], [-1, -1])
            at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.maybeInitCodecWithFallback(MediaCodecRenderer.java:854)
            at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.maybeInitCodec(MediaCodecRenderer.java:558)
            at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.onInputFormatChanged(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1240) 
            at com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.MediaCodecVideoRenderer.onInputFormatChanged(MediaCodecVideoRenderer.java:755) 
            at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.readToFlagsOnlyBuffer(MediaCodecRenderer.java:801) 
            at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.render(MediaCodecRenderer.java:700) 
            at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.doSomeWork(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:599) 
            at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:329) 
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103) 
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237) 
            at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67) 
         Caused by: android.media.MediaCodec$CodecException: Failed to initialize OMX.Exynos.avc.dec, error 0xfffffff4
            at android.media.MediaCodec.native_setup(Native Method)
            at android.media.MediaCodec.<init>(MediaCodec.java:1864)
            at android.media.MediaCodec.createByCodecName(MediaCodec.java:1842)
            at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.initCodec(MediaCodecRenderer.java:912)
            at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.maybeInitCodecWithFallback(MediaCodecRenderer.java:847)
            at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.maybeInitCodec(MediaCodecRenderer.java:558) 
            at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.onInputFormatChanged(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1240) 
            at com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.MediaCodecVideoRenderer.onInputFormatChanged(MediaCodecVideoRenderer.java:755) 
            at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.readToFlagsOnlyBuffer(MediaCodecRenderer.java:801) 
            at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.render(MediaCodecRenderer.java:700) 
            at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.doSomeWork(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:599) 
            at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:329) 
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103) 
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237) 
            at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67) 

package com.app.videopreloading
    import android.content.Context
    import android.net.Uri
    import android.os.Handler
    import android.util.Log
    import android.view.LayoutInflater
    import android.view.View
    import android.view.ViewGroup
    import android.widget.Toast
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    import com.google.android.exoplayer2.*
    import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ProgressiveMediaSource
    import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
    import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory
    import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.cache.CacheDataSource
    import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.cache.CacheDataSourceFactory
    import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.cache.SimpleCache
    import com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.Util
    import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.player_fragment.view.*
    
    class Adapter(private val arrayList: ArrayList<VideoItem>,private val context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder>(){
        private var videoUrl: String? = null
        private var cacheDataSourceFactory: CacheDataSourceFactory? = null
        val defaultHttpDataSourceFactory = DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("exoplayer_video")
    
        var exoplayer1 = arrayOfNulls<SimpleExoPlayer>(arrayList.size)
    
        private var simpleExoPlayer: SimpleExoPlayer? = null;
    
    
        private var mPlayerView: PlayerView? = null
    
        private var simpleCache: SimpleCache? = null
    
        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
            return ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.player_fragment, parent , false))
        }
    
        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return arrayList.size
        }
    
        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
            holder.setVideoData(position)
        }
    
        fun stop(){
            Log.e("Stop","stop")
            simpleExoPlayer?.playWhenReady = false
            Log.e("simpleExoPlayer",simpleExoPlayer.toString())
        }
    
        fun stopVideo(position: Int){
            Log.e("GetRendererType", simpleExoPlayer?.getRendererType(position).toString())
        }
    
        inner class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){
    
            var playerView = view.playerView;
            var title = view.title;
            var progressbar = view.progressBar5;
    
            init {
                mPlayerView = playerView
    
                title.setOnClickListener {
              //      play(adapterPosition)
                }
    
                playerView.setOnClickListener {
                    Toast.makeText(context, adapterPosition.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            }
    
            fun setVideoData(position: Int){
    
                simpleExoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(context)
    
                simpleCache = MyApp.simpleCache
    
                cacheDataSourceFactory = CacheDataSourceFactory(
                    simpleCache,
                    DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(context.let {
                        Util.getUserAgent(
                            it, "App"
                        )
                    }),
                    CacheDataSource.FLAG_IGNORE_CACHE_ON_ERROR
                )
    
                val videoUri = Uri.parse(arrayList[position].url)
                val mediaSource =
                    ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(cacheDataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(videoUri)
    
                playerView.player = simpleExoPlayer
                simpleExoPlayer?.playWhenReady = false
                simpleExoPlayer?.seekTo(0, 0)
                simpleExoPlayer?.repeatMode = Player.REPEAT_MODE_ALL
                simpleExoPlayer?.prepare(mediaSource, true, false)
    
    
                simpleExoPlayer?.addListener(object : Player.EventListener{
    
                    override fun onLoadingChanged(isLoading: Boolean) {
                        Log.e("onLoadingChanged", "Hello world")
    
                    }
    
                    override fun onSeekProcessed() {
                        Log.e("onSeekProcessed", "Hello world")
                    }
    
                    override fun onIsPlayingChanged(isPlaying: Boolean) {
                        Log.e("onIsPlayingChanged", "Hello world")
                    }
    
                    override fun onTimelineChanged(timeline: Timeline, reason: Int) {
                    }
    
                    override fun onPlayerStateChanged(playWhenReady: Boolean, playbackState: Int) {
                        Log.e("onPlayerStateChanged", playWhenReady.toString())
    
                        if (playWhenReady){
                            updateProgress()
                        }
                    }
                })
    
            }
    
            fun updateProgress(){
    
                var handler = Handler()
    
                val r: Runnable = object : Runnable {
                    override fun run() {
                        progressbar.progress = (simpleExoPlayer?.currentPosition!! * 100 / simpleExoPlayer!!.duration).toInt()
    
                        handler.postDelayed(this, 10)
                    }
                }
    
                handler.postDelayed(r, 1000)
            }
    
        }
    
    
    }
```

1. Please Let me how to do this it's very important for me to complete this task. I am trying make on swipe video play like tiktok or any other app which have this feature. Please let me know as soon as possible to solve this problem

I also tried to initialize array of object of simpleExoPlayer to handle efficiently onswipe stop and start but it gives me same error after 15 or 16 video.